# Put Form contents into list for MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a page containing one main form and multiple smaller duplicate forms. I am trying to post them both using one button with JQuery, and handle them in the order of: main form first then smaller forms second. However, when I attempt to access the smaller forms, I am getting data from only the last one. I was thinking that the best way to do it would be to put the smaller forms into a list, pass that to my handler, and then do a foreach loop through the list. How would I put the form information into a list before my handler uses it?
Here is my model:

```cs
public class SubmitModel
    { 
        [BindProperty]
        public Timelineinfo Timelineinfo { get; set; } //main form
        [BindProperty]
        public Media Medias { get; set; }//small form       
    }
```

My controller:

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("/Submit/Submit")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] //Main form handler
        public async Task<IActionResult> Submit(SubmitModel model)
        {           
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //Removed for brevity, but
                //Fill out some more values in main form then submit main form to Database,
            }           
            return View("Pages/Submit.cshtml", model);
        }

      
        [Route("/Submit/MediaAdd")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] //Add media form handler
        public async Task<IActionResult> MediaAdd(SubmitModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
               //Removed for brevity, but
               //Fill out some more values in small form then submit small form to Database
            }            
            return View("Pages/Submit.cshtml", model);
        }
```

And a truncated version of my small form (main form looks similar but with with `Submit` instead of `MediaAdd`:

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("MediaAdd", "Timeline", FormMethod.Post))
{  
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-row">
            <label asp-for="Medias.Blurb" class="control-label">Blurb<span class="text-danger ml-1">*</span> <span class="text-muted ml-1">Explain what is in the media</span></label>
            <input asp-for="Medias.Blurb" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Medias.Blurb" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="ml-3 col-4">
                <label class="form-check-label">Is there any blood or gore in the video?<span class="text-danger ml-1">*</span></label>
                <div class="form-check m-2 d-inline">
                    <input type="radio" asp-for="Medias.Gore" class="form-check-input" value="0">
                    <label class="form-check-label">No</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check m-2 d-inline">
                    <input type="radio" asp-for="Medias.Gore" class="form-check-input" value="1" />
                    <label class="form-check-label">Yes</label>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Medias.Gore" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Finally, how I am currently submitting my forms:

```
$('#submitButton').click(function () {
  $('form').submit();
});
```

Comment: Why jquery submit? You can do it by form's submit button. Yes, combining form data in one model is the right approach. Now is there any issue?

Comment: I want to submit them all together on the click of only one submit button, and as far as I know, this is the way to do it

Comment: Where did you put submit button? For form submit through `Html.BeginForm`, following link would be helpful https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-MVC-HtmlBeginForm-Tutorial-with-example.aspx

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really see how that link helps, the forms are all submitting, but because they are not in a list, the small forms are overriding each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an example based on your requirement, you may refer to it:

**Model:**

```
public class SubmitModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public Timelineinfo Timelineinfo { get; set; } 
    [BindProperty]
    public List<Media> Medias { get; set; }
}

public class Timelineinfo
{
    public int TimeId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Media
{
    public string Blurb { get; set; }
    public string Gore { get; set; }
}
```

**Main form View(Index):**

```
@model SubmitModel

<button id="AddMedia" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add Media</button>

@using (Html.BeginForm("MediaAdd", "Timeline", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-row">
            <label asp-for="Timelineinfo.TimeId" class="control-label">TimeId</label>
            <input asp-for="Timelineinfo.TimeId" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <label asp-for="Timelineinfo.Description" class="control-label">Description</label>
            <input asp-for="Timelineinfo.Description" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="subformsArea">

    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
}

@section scripts{ 
<script>
    var count = 0;
    $("#AddMedia").on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Timeline/Media',
            method: 'get',
            data: {data : count},
            success: function (result) {
                $("#subformsArea").append(result);
                count++;
            }
        })

    })
</script>

}
```

**Subform View(Partial View):**

```
@model SubmitModel

@{ 
    int i = ViewBag.Count;
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="form-row">
        <label asp-for="Medias[i].Blurb" class="control-label">Blurb<span class="text-danger ml-1">*</span> <span class="text-muted ml-1">Explain what is in the media</span></label>
        <input asp-for="Medias[i].Blurb" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Medias[i].Blurb" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="ml-3 col-4">
            <label class="form-check-label">Is there any blood or gore in the video?<span class="text-danger ml-1">*</span></label>
            <br />
            <div class="form-check m-2 d-inline">
                <input type="radio" asp-for="Medias[i].Gore" class="form-check-input" value="0">
                <label class="form-check-label">No</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check m-2 d-inline">
                <input type="radio" asp-for="Medias[i].Gore" class="form-check-input" value="1" />
                <label class="form-check-label">Yes</label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Medias[i].Gore" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public class TimelineController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Route("/Submit/MediaAdd")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] //Add media form handler
    public IActionResult MediaAdd(SubmitModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Removed for brevity, but
            //Fill out some more values in small form then submit small form to Database
        }
        return View("Pages/Submit.cshtml", model);
    }

    public IActionResult Media(int data)
    {
        ViewBag.Count = data;
        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this works great. I had spent the past way too many hours trying setting up a much more clunky method.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure why but when I run your code and press the add media button, my equivalent of your ```MediaAdd``` method is firing.

Comment: Make sure the button id `AddMedia` is unique and the ajax url is correct.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear, I am getting the new form to appear, but immediately after it breaks. So the get new form method is working well, but right after it runs, the ```MediaAdd``` function runs too, when it shouldn't be. https://imgur.com/a/Um5Bu8k

Comment: Confused, it didn't happen on my side, do you have other  scripts that may trigger the submit action.

Comment: Ah, I figured out what was causing it. So when i hit the add media button, ASP.NET's jquery validation was running and popping up errors. In an attempt to fix the issue, I added a ```formnovalidate="formnovalidate"``` onto the add media button. It was removing the error messages but also posting the form. My method no longer fires, which is good, but how would you suggest I remove the error messages?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it. The simpler the better:

```
<form action='myAction' method='postOrGet'>
//subform 1
<input name='inputA' subform='s1'.../>
//subform 2
<input name='inputX' subform='s2'.../>
...
<button type='submit'>submit</button>
</form>
```

Then you can easily separate submitted data based on the "subform" attribute (s1, s2. etc)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think I can do this. The number of small forms is unknown, the user can add or remove however many they want. I am generating each small form from a ajax request to a partial so I can't have individual identifying features.

Comment: @Bubinga there is a problem if you load multiple partial view, because the subforms has a radio button in it, if you add two or more subforms to the main form then you can just choose one radio button  since they have the same name attribute.